Get query param value form get request with cypress tests
In my app once the user logs in an automatic get request is fired to with the query params of an id value. I need to get that id.
I tried with intercept but it seems like that there is not way of storing that query param value in a variable.
    cy.intercept('GET', '/api/equipment*').as('getEquipment');



    cy.login(emailClientTest, password);

    cy.wait(10000);

    cy.wait('@getEquipment').then((interception) => {
      companyUUID = interception.request.query.company_uuid;

      


You've not given full details of the test, but in Cypress the way to store data is via aliases.
See Variables and aliases for more info.
An alias from an interception could be set as follows:
cy.wait('@getEquipment')
  .its('request.query.company_uuid')
  .as('company_uuid')

... later

cy.get('@company_uuid')
  .then(company_uuid => {
    ... use the id here
  })

